# In my picker view array data is not loading?

Tags: ios, swift3, uipickerview

In this I try to load picker view with data but not able to load data and it is showing as shown in below image that only empty picker view is displaying i was trying from a long time can any one help me what's wrong in implementing ?
[image]

```
    var firstName : String = ""
    var lastName : String = ""
    var mobileNumber : Int = 0
    var email : String = ""
    var defaultValue = 1
    let url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bPmyumGWeW?indent=2"
    var dateofbirth : String = ""
    var Gender : String = ""
    var genderArray = [String]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let picker = UIPickerView()
        picker.isHidden = true
        picker.delegate = self
        DateofBirthTextfield.delegate = self
        selectGenderTextField.inputView = picker
        MyaccountJsonWithURL()
        genderArray = ["Male","Female"]

    }

    func MyaccountJsonWithURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                //  print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Detail"))
                if let profileArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "profile") as? NSArray {
                    for array in profileArray {
                        if let profileDict = array as? NSDictionary {
                            if let firstName = profileDict.value(forKey: "first name"){
                                self.firstName.append(firstName as! String)
                            }
                            if let lastName = profileDict.value(forKey: "last name"){
                                self.lastName.append(lastName as! String)
                            }
                            self.mobileNumber = profileDict.value(forKey: "mobile") as! Int
                            print(self.mobileNumber)
                            if let emailId = profileDict.value(forKey: "email"){
                                self.email.append(emailId as! String)
                            }
                            self.dateofbirth = profileDict.value(forKey: "dob") as! String
                            if let gender = profileDict.value(forKey: "gender"){
                                self.Gender.append(gender as! String)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.FirstNameTextfield.text = self.firstName
                    self.LastNameTextfield.text = self.lastName
                    self.MobileNumberTextfield.text = String(describing: self.mobileNumber)
                    self.EmailIdTextfield.text = self.email
                    self.DateofBirthTextfield.text = String(describing: self.dateofbirth)
                    self.selectGenderTextField.text = self.Gender
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return genderArray.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return genderArray[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectGenderTextField.text = genderArray[row]
        self.view.endEditing(false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` you set picker as `hidden`. Set `picker.isHidden = false` to display it

Comment: no its displaying i had shown in the figure that gray

Comment: @Thiru Did you solved it? Accept the answer if it worked :)

Comment: ya its displaying now i thought that if data is not loading but i thought that line will make whole picker view will hide

Comment: Is it possible to change the height of picker view for this  ? @Bali

Answer (score 1):

**type & replace on picker.hidden = true**

```
picker.hidden = false
```